# cx-Freeze build failed with lto-wrapper error in anaconda python3.7.7 environment

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.7, cx-freeze

Having a problem with building cx-Freeze in anaconda's python 3.7.7 environment. I simply used the following command:

```
conda create -n py3.7 python=3.7.7
conda activate py3.7
pip install cx-Freeze=6.6
```

However the installation failed with the following error message:

```
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cx_Freeze/bases
gcc -pthread -B /home/syheung/anaconda3/envs/py3.7/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/source/bases/Console.o -L/home/syheung/anaconda3/envs/py3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.7m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cx_Freeze/bases/Console-cp37-linux-x86_64 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lrt -lm -s -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/lib -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../lib
lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream in file ‘/home/syheung/anaconda3/envs/py3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.a’ generated with LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 8.1
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: gcc returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/home/syheung/anaconda3/envs/py3.7/compiler_compat/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

My operating system is Pop_OS 20.04 LTS. I also noticed that the python installed with anaconda is using GCC 7.3.0, whereas my system's using GCC 9.4.0. I'm not sure if that contributes to the error above.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
More information on environments:

```
$ conda --version
> conda 4.10.3
$ anaconda --version
> anaconda Command line client (version 1.8.0)
$ uname -a
> Linux p-dsk 5.13.0-7614-generic #14~1631647151~20.04~930e87c-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 17 00:26:31 UTC  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```